# How t integrate google maps with cooja simulator

Tags: networking, contiki, cooja

How Integrate Google earth with Cooja Simulator?
I am now working in IoT, and I want to connect google earth or map with cooja simulator in order to distribute the wireless sensors on the map . I read the tutorial of Cooja and I watched many related vedios about this topic. but I dont get and helpful information to do this .. can any one advise me what should I do because I still new in cooja simulator

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cloud service to capture and make sense of sensor data, and connect things to the Internet, for example use https://ubidots.com/ and get the API key and create your specific variables.

You can study `IoT in 5 days (Revision 1.0)` free book and go to *Chapter 6: Sending Data to Ubidots*, or `IoT in 5 days (Revision 1.1)` *Chapter 5.3 and 5.4.*